# How do I perform decimal arithmetic in Perl?

Tags: perl, decimal

I'm working on an accounting script written in Perl and I'm wondering what's the 'proper' way to perform decimal arithmetic calculations. For instance, I want to insure that comparisons like these work correctly:

```
"0.1" + "0.1" + "0.1" == "0.3"
"258.9" * "2000" == "517800"
...
```

In Python I'd use the `Decimal` type for the values, but what do I do in Perl?

Comment: Math::BigRat and Math::Decimal would do the trick.

Comment: Remove the quotes from your decimals and integers.

Comment: @Missaka Wijekoon, The quotes are harmless. You're missing the point. Try `perl -E'say 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3 ? "equal" : "not equal"'`

Comment: Another *very* old tactic is to do integer math against the smallest unit.  Instead of 0.1 dollars use 10 cents.

Comment: This question has got my interest, would love to hear an answer for why adding and printing them works but comparing them doesnt.

Comment: @tjd: I get input as strings, and it's not only amounts of money (could be rate, percentage, etc.)

Comment: Great.  Get your input as strings, we all do.  You should still know which items are "money" and convert to the smallest appropriate unit.  "Cents" for US currency, "eighths of a dollar" for US stock transactions, etc.  You should also be *very* clear about your "rounding" algorithm when playing around with "rates" & "percentages".  Don't just "hope for the best".

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Because exact non-integer numbers in decimal (our base-10 UI to numbers) often cannot get exact representations in binary, so will always have some (very small) rounding error. The exact value of the error will differ for different operations on the numbers. As to why printing "works": the print routines have a precision cutoff.

Comment: @tjd that's very fragile when used inside calculations.

Comment: @tjd consider some calculation dividing it by two, then multiplying it by three. You don't want data to be lost there.

Comment: @Elyse which is why I said that you need to be very aware of your rounding.  Regardless of how much you don't want to loose "information", you still can't bill or reimburse anyone in fractional smallest units.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(NOTE: There is [Math::Currency](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Currency) but it is currently broken).

Use [`Math::BigFloat`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigFloat) to represent numbers as arbitrary precision objects.

```
use Math::BigFloat;

print Math::BigFloat->new(0.1) +
      Math::BigFloat->new(0.1) +
      Math::BigFloat->new(0.1) == Math::BigFloat->new(0.3);
```

You can do this automatically with [`bignum`](https://metacpan.org/pod/bignum)...

```
use bignum;

print 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3;
```

***BUT!*** the magic only works on *numbers*.  If you try to add strings together it won't work, the magic comes too late.  You have to explicitly force them to be numbers.  To numify a string you can add 0 to the string, like `$a += 0`.  Or you can force an equation to be done as bignums by starting with `0 +` and it will cascade down the line.

```
use bignum;

$a = "0.1";
$b = "0.1";
$c = "0.1";
$d = "0.3";

# False
print $a + $b + $c == $d;

# True
print 0 + $a + $b + $c == $d;
```

Two caveats.

First, this all comes at a heavy performance cost.  Not only for doing arbitrary precision math, but for all the methods and overloading magic.  Benchmark it to see if this is acceptable.  Fortunately `bignum` only upgrades numbers in its scope, not the whole program.  It's also safe to use those numbers outside of `bignum`'s scope, any math done with them will also be upgraded.

Second, [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) will preserve significant figures.  Math::BigFloat will not.

Comment: `Math::BigFloat` seems to work for me, although it's obviously still floating point arithmetic. I'm surprised there's no core module to do decimal arithmetic.

Comment: @engene y, Math::BigRat does lossless arithmetic, and it has been in core since 5.8.0.

Comment: @eugeney It's done with integers under the hood. `0.01` becomes `1` with an exponent of `2`. Every arbitrary precision library has to have a limit to its precision else you can very, very easily exhaust memory. For example, `1/3`. Python's Decimal stops at 30 places. Math::BigFloat goes out to 40. [Math::BigFloat discusses this problem](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigFloat#Accuracy-vs.-Precision). If you want more precision, use [Math::BigRat](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigRat).  It stores fractions as fractions. `use bigrat; print 1/3` gives `1/3`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you might use [Math::Decimal](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Decimal) for division:

```
use 5.024003; # use `say'
use Math::Decimal qw( 
                     dec_mul_pow10 
                     dec_neg 
                     dec_rndiv 
                    ); 
my $num_1 = '3'; 
my $num_2 = '7'; 
my $precision = '3'; 

# You want to get three digits after the decimal, 
# so multiply dividend by 1000, divide to get an 
# integer quotient, and then divide that quotient 
# by 1000. 
my $dividend_up_some = dec_mul_pow10( $num_1, $precision ); 
# Rounding by `NEAR_EVN' is "bankers' rounding." 
my $quotient_up_some = 
          dec_rndiv( 'NEAR_EVN', $dividend_up_some, 
                     $num_2 ); 
# Move it back down to get your desired precision after 
# the decimal. 
my $quotient = 
      dec_mul_pow10( $quotient_up_some, 
                     dec_neg( $precision ) ); 
say "$num_1 / $num_2 = $quotient";
```

Run this program and here is the output:

```
3 / 7 = 0.429
```

Change $precision to '10' and here is the output:

```
3 / 7 = 0.4285714286
```

Answer (score -4):

Best way I know how is to test with absolute diff being less than a tolerance.  For example:

perl -e '$x = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1; $y = 0.3; $q = abs($x - $y) < 0.0001 ? "EQUAL" : "NOT EQUAL"; print $q . "\n";'

Comment: Use of floating point numbers in an accounting scenario is a remarkably bad idea, not least of which is the accumulation of these round-off errors.

Comment: You can get the actual epsilon from [POSIX.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX).  `use POSIX qw(DBL_EPSILON);`